# How does one Capture MP3s in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, mp3, audio-recording

I was able to capture audio in the WAV format through Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio"). However, is there a way to capture audio in the MP3 format in J2ME?

Answer (score 1):

It will likely depend on the platform in question, you would have to check the different device implementations you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

Rory, what do you mean?
I was really asking for the String for the createPlayer(String s) method. J2ME automatically records to a WAV file, but I was wondering if I could request it to record to MP3. Of course if that MP3 argument did not work, a MediaException would be thrown. Please forgive me if it seems that I am missing the point of your response.

Comment: I meant that the spec may require WAV support, but MP3 support, if available, will depend on each platform. Those that do support it may then require different arguments/class types in order to do so. I'm of course speculating here, I've no idea if it's actually possible.